# Servlet giving 404 once context path is added

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, embedded-jetty

I have been scratching my head for some time on what seems to be a trivial problem. I have a webapp where the context on the webappcontext is defined as below. This code is to setup the embedded jetty webserver before starting it up. (I am not trying to change the context at runtime).

```
webAppContext.setContextPath("/MyApp");
```

If I then use the below code for my servlet context, everything works:

```
    servletContext.setContextPath("/");
    servletContext.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new LoginServlet()), "/LoginServlet");
```

But, now there are 2 different session IDs. One for "/" and one for "/MyApp".

If I change my servlet context code to the below, I am unable to find the url for it:

```
    servletContext.setContextPath("/MyApp");
    servletContext.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new LoginServlet()), "/LoginServlet");
```

I have tried urls such as, but they all give 404 not found:

```
 - http://localhost:8123/LoginServlet [which works in the first case]
 - http://localhost:8123/MyApp/LoginServlet
 - http://localhost:8123/MyApp/MyApp/LoginServlet
```

My servlet url is defined as

```
urlPatterns = { "/LoginServlet" }
```

I am using Eclipse for development and embedded Jetty for the web server. Any help or pointers will be appreciated. I am not an expert on this by any means and no amount of trolling the web has helped to this point.

Thanks in advance...

**SOLVED**
Found the "trivial" issue. Had a blank session handler on the WebAppContext which was eating up all the requests sent to '/MyApp'.

Comment: the code `servletContext.setContextPath` is it even valid? Does your code compile?

Comment: @MaVRoSCy Yes it does :-) This is part of embedded jetty coding. The variable name makes it seem like pseudo-code.

Comment: Hm... you might be mixing up two different ways of using Jetty. One is for web applications and one is for defining single servlet based applications. Would be nice to see complete bootstrap code. I have not that many experience with Jetty, but looking at the JavaDoc you should not be working with `ServletContext` if you are creating `WebAppContext` (http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/servlet/ServletContextHandler.html#addServlet%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: @PavelHoral Thanks! That was a very interesting observation. I did not realize that WebAppContext was inherited from ServletContext. I have now removed the latter and am working exclusively with the WebAppContext. However, the problem remains. Once I set the contextpath, I am unable to find the url for the servlet. Am thinking that I might have a problem with the second parameter in the addServlet call, but not sure what to try there.

Comment: @PavelHoral Thanks to your pointer, I solved my issue. I had an empty session handler pointing to my WebAppContext. This was presumably consuming all the requests sent on /MyApp and not calling my servlets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue!

Had an empty sessionHandler pointing to the webAppContext which was eating up all the requests. Once I removed it, everything worked as advertised.

Thanks to all responders.